# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_File

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, admin-panel, fatal-error, zend-framework

I get the following error returned when clicking `Edit` or `Add New Customer` in `Admin >> Customers >> Manage Customers >> "Edit" or "Add New Customer"`

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_File::shutdown() in /var/app/current/lib/Zend/Log.php on line 366

Lines 363 to 367 highlighted below

```
{
    /** @var Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract $writer */
    foreach($this->_writers as $writer) {
        $writer->shutdown();
    }
```

How do I fix this?

We have not experienced this error before and the code within the files indicated in the error has not changed from prior application versions.

I should also add that when trying to `Create a New Order` on the backend, the `Create New Customer` button and `links to existing customers` do not respond when clicked. Not sure if the errors are related but they started at the same time.

Comment: You were likely hacked, see this: https://sansec.io/research/naturalfreshmall-mass-hack

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me. Magento 1.9. No change in file or database between yesterday and today, when the error start.
Restoring a backup (file and db from yesterday) error is fix.

Comment: You were likely hacked, see this: https://sansec.io/research/naturalfreshmall-mass-hack